# My Qt built with msvc2010 does not have QtOpenGLd4.dll?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

1. Do I have to build a debug-and-release QT ? Now, with default option (-release) I see how release and debug versions are created. (###.dll /lid and ###d.dll /lib )
   I’m a bit confused…. The ### files are ‘pure’ release versions and ###d. ‘pure’ debug versions ? What is the difference between this build and a ‘debug_and_release’ build ?
2. On release mode I can compile my app but on debug mode I have a link error: cannot find QtOpenGLd4.dll.
   If I look at my /bin folder I see there is a #4.dll / #4.lib / #4d.dll /4d.lib for every qt library except QtOpenGLd4.dll. (I have only the release version ) What is happening? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Qt with `-release` it will not build debug versions of the libraries, or this is a bug in the configure app, which I really doubt is actually present.

The `d` suffix implies they are "pure" debug builds, and the "pure" (whatever that word would mean here) release builds are those without the suffix. Qt does not know of a ReleaseWithDebug build like CMake does, it only has the equivalent of Release and Debug.

If you only have QtOpenGLd4.dll missing and you built from source, just go to Qtbuild/src/opengl and do an `nmake` or `nmake debug` and see what happens.

Comment: nmake debug shows a lot of warnings and does nothing.... 
I am not a compiler expert...  I have used the <http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC >

Comment: nmake debug shows a lot of warnings and does nothing.... (That is no QtOpenGld4.dll was created)
I am not a compiler expert...  I have used the <http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC >
The configure process are right.   
And  ... repeat I have release and debug files for the other libs.
Any other idea? Thanks (Sorry , I have spent the 5 minutes for editing... )